# A Perl Program Which divides a String by spaces between them?

Tags: perl, split

I want my program to divide the string by the spaces between them

```
$string = "hello how are you";
```

The output should look like that:

```
hello  
how  
are  
you
```

Comment: We might be able to read better if it's not in all **bold CAPS**.

Comment: What research did you do? This is a pretty basic request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this is a few different ways.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "hello how are you";  

my @first  = $string =~ /\S+/g;    # regex capture non-whitespace
my @second = split ' ', $string;   # split on whitespace
my $third  = $string;
$third =~ tr/ /\n/;                # copy string, substitute space for newline
# $third =~ s/ /\n/g;              # same thing, but with s///
```

The first two creates arrays with the individual words, the last creates a different single string. If all you want is something to print, the last will suffice. To print an array do something like:

```
print "$_\n" for @first;
```

Notes:

- Normally, regex capture requires parentheses `/(\S+)/`, but when the `/g` modifier is used, and parentheses are omitted, the entire match is returned.
- When using capture this way, you need to assure list context on the assignment. If the left hand parameter is a scalar, you would force list context with parentheses: `my ($var) = ...`

Comment: I don't see why anyone would downvote this. It is a first-class answer, as most of the times from TLP.

Comment: @NikhilJain Thank you. Yes, don't worry, random DVs happens.

Answer (score 4):

I think like simple....

```
$string = "hello how are you";  
print $_, "\n" for split ' ', $string;
```

Answer (score 2):

`@Array = split(" ",$string);` then the `@Array` contain the answer

Answer (score 0):

You need a [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) for dividing the string by spaces like

```
use strict;

my $string = "hello how are you";

my @substr = split(' ', $string); # split the string by space

{
  local $, = "\n"; # setting the output field operator for printing the values in each line
  print @substr;
}

Output:

hello
how
are
you
```

Comment: I think a little explanation would make this answer better.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I suspect the reasons are: You should `use warnings`, you should not split on a single whitespace, unless you by design want empty fields in case of multiple consecutive spaces, using a block for the print is valid code, but looks odd, `$,` can be obscure to some people, and a for-loop is more readable.

Comment: @TLP: Thanks for the explaination.I took the same example given by OP that's why I used the single whitespace.

Comment: I did not notice before, but it seems 3/4 answers on this question have been downvoted (my answer included). So perhaps its just a serial downvoter and nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Split with regexp to account for extra spaces if any:

```
my $string = "hello how are you";
my @words = split /\s+/, $string; ## account for extra spaces if any
print join "\n", @words
```